# Clearing empty element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hello i am not sure why those empty elements still there even i clear (or clear function does not work guess). Might you guys have a look on this. I am getting this array after add another value into same array.I am asking whats is happening behind not just solving code thank you

[image]

this is function when ever i click button it adds 4 into DVALUE array.

```
if("q"+idcount+"d" == this.id){
    DVALUE[dcount++] = 4;
//  alert("D ARRAY"+DVALUE.toString());
    }
```

And this is when ever i click revert button it will remove last added number

```
  if ("d" === qwer) {
    // alert(""+DVALUE.toString());
    DVALUE.pop();
    cleararrayD(); // also calling this function to remove empty elements when ever this if occurs
}
```

And this is cleararrayD Function

```
function cleararrayD() {
    lens = DVALUE.length, i;
    for (i = 0; i < lens; i++) DVALUE[i] && DVALUE.push(DVALUE[i]); // copy non-empty values to the end of the array
    DVALUE.splice(0, lens);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey i got answer for my question. As you can see it clears array but i put element at wrong indexes. Everytime i click button **Dcount++** adding indexes so i just doing this  **Dcount--** in my removing functions

`DVALUE[dcount++] = 4;`

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking whats is happening behind not just solving code

The `.length` of `DVALUE` array does not change at `cleararrayD()` function call as an element is `.push()`ed to `DVALUE` array for each index of `DVALUE` before `.splice()` is called with original array `.length` at second parameter, removing the preceding elements to the elements `.push()`ed to the array.

Comment: What is input and expected result?

Comment: input is just numbers and result is little bit complicated i am getting all those numbers by index there should be 0-11 index, all index has number that is why i need to clear empty elements otherwise i get undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" elements? Can you create a stacksnippets of jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/5b6xLpfs/12/](jsfiddle.net) here you go as you can see click 4 button after that remove it and do it again you will see empty indexes

Comment: guess i almost what i done wrong i forget to minus index counter of every array DVALUE[**Dcount++**]= 4; if am i right i need to code this dcount-- in remove button ?

Comment: The linked jsfiddle returns expected result, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151664/discussion-between-munkhdelger-tumenbayar-and-guest271314).